# alernative for a cookie

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies

i have made an app on facebook its url is http://a.pgtb.me/xSdmSr. It is basically a voting app it saves a cookie in the browser as soon as someone votes a cookie is saved to avoid revoting but users are deleting the cookie & voting again & i do not want this to be done i.e. revoting.
1) I am looking for a solution that somehow i can restrict a single vote can be casted using a single facebook id.

or

2)  saving a cookie which if found redirects a user to another page giving an alert you already voted only if the user is the same who voted from that browser and could not be deleted by the user.

or

3) or the same could be done without using a cookie or any other alternative solution OR CAN I DO THE SAME USING FLASH COOKIES IS YES THEN PLZ TELL ME HOW.

note:- please give a solution by using javascript, jquery, html,css only no php, jsp or other server side scripting

Comment: Anything you do on client-side can be manipulated on the client-side using one tool or another. Remember: "Client-side security is no security"

Comment: Using Server Side scripting you can track `facebook_id` of users easily.

Comment: how can i do it..??? @ Shri

Comment: how can i do it @Shri m not able to get the facebook id of the user :'(

Comment: people who done voting for particular poll, store their ids in array or table. And each time when user come to vote check for existence of his/her id in your array. This is just an idea you can implement it in your way.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that no matter what you do, considering client side programming, there will always be some way to cheat. So if you really want to make this work without such thing, you will need to go for server side programming.

Comment: but m not allowed to do so give me some method i'll try n check if facebook supports that too or i could do is insert an iframe which could install n check for the same facebook id if an same facebook id is found then it gives a prompt n redirects on ciking ok

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find what is provided through there api. Use the id and store it somewhere and if the id is stored you cant vote again.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: cookies can be changed by the client, so this doen't really help

Comment: I din't meen cookies when I wrote store. I was thinking more about a serverside repository.